# Fastai - how to prediction after use load_learner in cpu

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, fast-ai

I'm doing a Text Classification (NLP) model using fastai train on googlecolab (gpu) after I load the model using load_learner without any error but when I change the cpu usage, I get an error "RuntimeError: _th_index_select not supported on CPUType for Half"
Is there any way for me to predict cpu usage results?

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.text import *
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
defaults.device = torch.device('cpu')
@np_func
def f1(inp,targ): return f1_score(targ, np.argmax(inp, axis=-1))
path = Path('/content/drive/My Drive/Test_fast_ai')
learn = load_learner(path)
learn.predict("so sad")
```

---

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-3775eb2bfe91> in <module>()
----> 1 learn.predict("so sad")

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1504         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   1505         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 1506     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1507 
   1508 

RuntimeError: _th_index_select not supported on CPUType for Half
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. Are you training your model with the parameter `to_fp16()`? I fix the issue by removing this parameter from the learner. For instance, when I was training with the following command line I got RuntimeError when using the model to predict in a cpu environment.

```
learn_c = text_classifier_learner(data_clas, AWD_LSTM, drop_mult=0.5, metrics=[accuracy]).to_fp16()
```

To fix I just remove the suffix `.to_fp16()` and everything went smoothly.